Display JSON data or a dictionary so thats it's collapsable in a Python Jupyter Notebook
Is it possible to display JSON data or a dictionary so it's collapsable and interactive (HTML display) within a Python Jupyter Notebook?

You can use the JSON package to read the JSON file into a dictionary and then display the output in a Jupyter Notebook using the IPython API as below:
import json
from IPython.display import display, JSON

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
display(JSON(data, expanded=True))

Example:

